# How to "tint" UIVisualEffectView on iOS 8+? Or, create a blurred background view with a tint color?

Tags: uikit, uinavigationbar, uivisualeffectview

Self-explanatory. `UIVisualEffectView` only has a light, dark, and "extra light" tint variation. Is there a way to tint with a color instead, such as the tint color of the app?

`UINavigationBar` sort of does this, I think, in that it has transparency and blur... but also a tint color.

Third-party libraries are OK, but I'm not sure where to look for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can tint the UIVisualEffectView using this library:
https://github.com/efremidze/VisualEffectView

Comment: This seems like the correct and best way to do it, but unfortunately uses a private API.

Comment: Yup, hopefully Apple adds tintColor to the UIBlurEffect.

Comment: FYI no longer works in iOS 16+

Answer (score 3):

Set a UIView with an alpha of 0.5 or so with a background color. In front of that put a UIVisualEffectView. Remember to not set the visual effect view as a subview of the first background view.

That should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `FXBlurView` is the way to go currently for tinted blurs. https://github.com/nicklockwood/FXBlurView

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe put it in a UIView that had a semi-opaque background color of the opacity to your liking...